# android remove ExbandableListview scroller

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, expandablelistview

[image]

Hi all,

I want to remove the scroller that appear in my expandable list view, my xml code is as following :

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandablelistview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="false" >
        </ExpandableListView>
```

but it is still appear when I scroll my list, can anyone help please ?

Comment: .setClickable(false) try this

Comment: Do you want clickevent on listView or not?

Comment: have you tried `android:scrollbars="none"`

Comment: I have set clicable = "false" and it is not working, I don't need click event on the list itself, but I have ontouch and onclick on the list items, and I have add android:scrollbars="none" in the attached code and also it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Thanks all for support, the problem was mine, as I was enabling the scrolling in the code, I'm so sorry

Answer (score 0):

android:fadeScrollbars="true" set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your listview and disable list view.

```
 enableDisableView(listView,false);

 public void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
            view.setEnabled(enabled);
            if ( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;
                for ( int idx = 0 ; idx < group.getChildCount() ; idx++ ) {
                    enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), enabled);
                }
            }
        }
```